# MLB Opening Easter Sunday

Tags: baseball, mlb, schedule

In 2015, [MLB Opening Day](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/schedule/#date=04/04/2015) was on Easter Sunday.  How many times has this happened in the history of the Major Leagues (counting either the American League and the National League, when they were more separate, but not other leagues)?

Specifically, in how many calendar years was the earliest game played during that calendar year across both the National League and the American League, on Easter Sunday?

Comment: 1) Your link points to April 7-9, 2015. Considering your question is about Opening Day 2015, is this intended? 2) As one answer states, a game the night before Opening Day has been broadcast on ESPN since 1994. This statement, along with [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_Day#History) statement of "Major League Baseball still reserves the title 'Opening Day' for the first day in which multiple games are played" seems to suggest that Opening Day in 2015 was April 6th, the day after Easter Sunday.

Comment: Good point on the first one - I must've copied it wrong; corrected.  On the second point, I'm not terribly interested in marketing speak: opening day is the first day of the season, as I clarify in the second paragraph.  MLB is welcome to call it whatever it wants.

Comment: Neither am I. Just looking for clarification is all. Nonetheless, that doesn't take away from your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/9091), a regular-season game the night before Opening Day has been televised on ESPN since 1994<sub>[(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_Day#History)</sub>. It is unclear if this makes Sunday Opening Day (as the first part of your question suggests) or Monday based on the statement "Major League Baseball still reserves the title 'Opening Day' for the first day in which multiple games are played<sub>[(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_Day#History)</sub>."

> Specifically, in how many calendar years was the earliest game played during that calendar year across both the National League and the American League, on Easter Sunday?

In any case, since 1994, the earliest *regular-season* game has been played on Easter Sunday six times:

- 2015
- [2013](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/2013.shtml)
- [2010](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/2010.shtml)
- [2002](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/2002.shtml)
- [1999](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/1999.shtml)
- [1994](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/1994.shtml)

NOTE: Before 1994, dating back to 1914, the earliest regular-season game of each respective year was never played on a Sunday. It was usually played on a Monday, Tuesday, or Wednesday, with anomalies in [1915](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/1915.shtml) and [1972](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/1972.shtml), in which the earliest regular-season game of those years were played on a Saturday.